# MySQL Find First Colum's String, Echo Second Column's

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns

Firstly, Sorry for bad English :(

I want key system like steam, origin or uplay. I give keys to user, user write that code into input, and code will echo user's code.

I have 1 Table. 2 Columns in it. 2 Rows for 2 Column. Like this:

```
.----------------------.
|  sifre  |  bizimkey  |
|______________________|
|  A5Sr2A | First Code |
|______________________|
|  FaQ1fS | Scnd. Code |
|______________________|
```

If user enters A5Sr2A into Input, PHP Echos "First Code". If user enters wrong code, Just appear alert.

I tried so many codes. I can run the code like this:

```
<?php
 if ($_POST['pass'] == "A5Sr2A") {
     {
         echo "First Code";
     }
 } else {
     header('Location:index.html');
 }
?>
```

But I don't want this. This is so challenging thing. I asked myself, "Why don't you use MySQL?"
I am trying 7 Hours. Really. I want to do that. I want learn MySQL. Please Help. THANKS!

```
    <? ob_start(); ?>
    <html>
        <link rel=stylesheet href="style.css">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "db";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "ERROR";
}
$result = m ysqli_query($con, "SELECT sifre FROM keyler");
if ($_POST['pass'] == $ result) {
    {
        $mykey = m ysqli_query($con, "SELECT bizimkey FROM keyler");
        echo $mykey;
    }
} else {
    header('Location:index.html');
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </html>
    <? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: What does your mysql code look like? How far did you get

Comment: http://jsbin.com/eGiWICo/1/edit

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what `mysqli_query` returns - see [the docs](http://uk1.php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: I was entered this. I haven't got it. I can't write the code like site says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, see below for a basic implementation example:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "db";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()!=0)//mysqli_connect_errno() returns 0 when there are no errors
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
$sifre_test = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT '1' FROM `keyler` WHERE `sifre`='".$sifre_test."'");
if($result!==false)
{
    //If $result !== false, the query was successful, so we'll try to grab a row
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    //$row will be null if there wasn't a row found where `sifre`=$sifre_test
    if(!is_null($row))
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `bizimkey` FROM `keyler` WHERE `sifre`='".$sifre_test."'");
        if($result!==false)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $bizimkey = $row['bizimkey'];
            echo $bizimkey;
        }
        else
        {
            die("bizimkey query failed");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    die("sifre query failed");
}
```

For a better understanding and more examples, see the documentation links below:

[`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)
[`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)

Comment: Thanks, but when I type FaQ1fS (The second one) It is not working. But first one, it is working very well.

Comment: @AtaGülalan Yea, sorry forgot the `WHERE` clause - it was just selecting the first row of the table, it now selects the row where `sifre` is `$_POST['pass']`

Comment: This Give Error: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given on line 13

Comment: In $sifre_test, it is '$sifre_test = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);'. I Suggest edit, THANKS A LOT! :)